# Gradle Build Failed, :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

Tags: java, android, gradle, build

In android studio, main activity, it says "cannot resolve symbol R". I have tried rebuilding and cleaning build. I have also updated buld.gradle to 2.1.3. The R is highlighted in red, and the path to the main activity is underlined in red. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should get an error message in gradle console why the build is failing. please provide the message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
 Go to File - Project Structure - Project and modify gradle version and Android Plugin version like the image

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvFTt.png)

Clean Project and Rebuild

if the problem persists. Go to project path and execute

```
gradle clean build
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Method: Go To File->Invalidate Caches /Restart and Click Invalidate Caches and Restart 
[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3KRr.png)
If it Still Not Resolved Try Again and Clean Project and Rebuild.
Happy Coding..!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your Android Studio as well? If that's not the case then try to update your android studio. Latest stable version is 2.1. If you have already updated it then problem might arose from the last activity or code you have written in your application. Such errors usually occurs when you try to manually update manifest or gradle or other build files. If that's the case then clean and build project will definitely solve the issue. These problems also arose after unexpected shutdown of IDE and internal IDE errors. If that's the case then android studio prompts you to report the issue to Google, you can do the same to seek further help.